# How to set X & Y Pivots in PropertyValuesHolder for a Rotation Animation

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

The following is my `View Animation` code:

```
final RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 63,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1);
```

For some reasons I have to use the `ObjectAnimator` now. And I am unable to set the pivots of the view as I did in the View Animation. I tried the following but failed miserably.

```
PropertyValuesHolder pvhx2 = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ROTATION, 0, 63, 
                                                 Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1);
ObjectAnimator rotateAnimation3 = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(animationView, pvhx2);
```

Please help me in setting the pivot for rotation in this animation.

Comment: Sorry I haven't test, but try this:
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 0f, 63f);

Answer (score 2):

You need set pivot in `ObjectAnimator` like this:

```
PropertyValuesHolder pvhPivotX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("pivotX",0.5);
PropertyValuesHolder pvhPivotY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("pivotY",0.5);
ObjectAnimator rotateAnimation3 = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(animationView, pvhPivotX, pvhPivotY, ...);
```